# rake task replace rather than create new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have this rake task

```
Event.find_or_create_by(
  time: row[9],
  date: row[10],
  event_type: word1,
  eventimage: row[4],
  eventname: eventname,
  eventvenuename: location,
  event: eventname,
  eventlink1: eventlink1,
  eventlink2: eventlink2
)
```

Now what's happening is `eventlink1` may be inputted the first time and on the first time the `eventlink2` will be `null`. If I run it again and `eventlink2` now has data to be populated, it creates a new row, rather than updating the existing one.

How can I make this update the existing row rather than creating a new one?

Answer (score 0):

`find_or_create_by` creates a new row if it doesn't find one that matches the field you give it, and when you give a `nil` value, it translates that to the SQL `WHERE eventlink2 IS NULL`, so the second time it will not find an exact match.

You should break that command into separate a `find_by` query and `create` command.

If you want to match field that has `NULL` value in the database you can include `nil` in the query:

```
event = Event.find_by(
   ...
   eventlink2: [eventlink2, nil]
)

if event
  event.update(...)
else
  Event.create(...)
end
```

Comment: Isn't this still doing just the same? Wouldn't i be looking at something like an findandupdate or create?

Comment: No. `find_or_create_by` is only a replacement for `find_by` and `create` if their arguments are the same. You need to call `find_by` with different argument.

Comment: Oh, I forgot about the `update`. You'll need to put that into the `else` branch of the `if`.

Comment: or better yet, invert the if to avoid the negation: if event => update, else => create

Comment: Not sure thats going to work is it? surely if i have multiple eventlinks i'll have to search across every field? (i have 5 links, I put all 5 links and it didnt work, It still created a new event row rather doing an update

Comment: Plus, some events have the same name, So its messing that up a little also